# Put csrf token on every route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, csrf

i made a csrf implementation on my nodejs web app.
but the csrf token only gets attached if i go through the `/login` route.
how can i do that it gets implemented on every route without causing errors?
or another idea for implementing it correctly?

i don't think that using a wildcard `**` will help

this is the code for my csrf code:

```
app.use(
  attachCsrfToken(
    "/login",
    "csrfToken",
    (Math.random() * 100000000000000000).toString()
  )
);

function attachCsrfToken(url, cookie, value) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // console.log(req.url, url);

    if (req.url == url) {
      res.cookie(cookie, value);
    }

    next();
  };
}
```

Is there a better way of implementing it?

Comment: do you use `csurf` module?

Comment: @dimitristseggenes no. i copy pasted this method and this method is being used in functions in a way that i don't really understand, so i don't wanna break the whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a middleware which validates the user and url and add this to any route that you want to validate.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

function attachCsrfToken(req,res,next) {
    // validate request
    if (req.url == url) {
      res.cookie(cookie, value);
      next();
    }

    
    // if not valid throw error
    res.JSON({success:false,code:403,message:'Unauthorized Access'})
  };
router.use(
  "/api/someroute",
  attachCsrfToken,
  require("./handlers/somePath").someFunction
);
```

Comment: didn't understand what you did here and how it's different from what i did?

Comment: Hey @MendiSterenfeld, sorry for late response but in your function you are always checking if req.url === url(which in your case is "/login", so that is why i have made a generic middleware and you can pass it in any route that you want. Hope it is clear now.